# Powershell Copy folders and files while maintaining the folder hierarchy

Tags: powershell-3.0

I want to copy files from one location to another, and the files should be in the same folders as the source. When I use the following script, it copies the files, but it does not copy the folders in the source folder. Any suggestions?

```
$a=Get-ChildItem C:\temp\_pdf_list -recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*pdf" -and $_.name -notlike "*prth*"}

$a

foreach($x in $a) {copy-item  -path $x.FullName "c:\temp\_pdfs_ck" -whatif}
```

Notice that the destination path does not put the file into a subfolder called 1001 the way I need.

Output:

```
What if: Performing operation "Copy File" on Target "Item: C:\temp\_pdf_list\1001\10010001.pdf Destination: C:\temp\_pdfs_ck\10010001.pdf".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally one would use a tool like `robocopy`, but I've never tried with both inclusive (add parameters after source and destination folders) and exclusive (`/xf pattern`) file name matching at the same time.

To do this in PowerShell you need to construct a complete output path: if just a destination folder is provided to `copy-item` then the source filename, but not the relative path is supplied.

So, something like:

```
$dest = $x.FullName.Replace('C:\temp\_pdf_list', 'c:\temp\_pdfs_ck')
copy-item -path $x.FullName -Destination $dest
```

Note:

1. I'm not using the `-replace` operator because that takes a regex, and normal filename characters (like `\` are significant to regexes.
2. Why not perform this all in a single pipeline:

   ```
   Get-ChildItem … | Where-Object … | Foreach-Object { $dest = …; Copy-Item … }
   ```

   this avoids creating a, potentially large, array, for the intermediate collection which you're only
   using in the next statement?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The reason I didn't use robocopy is I am not allowed to install it on my machine. I am intrigued by your comment about a single pipeline. Can you provide the full code based on my example as I am new to Powershell and am not quite sure what to put for .... .

Comment: Robocopy has been standard since Vista/Windows Server 2008. If you're using PowerShell 3.0, you're running at least Windows 7 or Server 2008R2. Which means there's nothing you need to install - you should already have it.

Comment: @user1476427: Replace the ellipses (`…`) with the same parameters as in your code.

Comment: I didn't realize Robocopy was on my machine. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Copy-Item -Path \\Server\Example -Container -Destination D:\Example -Force -Recurse
```